# Android parsing RSS Feed URL

Tags: android, parsing

When I am trying to parse the link tags from rssfeed

```
url-http://www.mobileapp.pcmac.org/mobile/xml/sisapp.asp?sid=353&pn=news2
```

I am getting the link tags correctly, but I am unable to use that link tags to parse the website content why the parsed link tags are not working to get the document using jsoup jar.
Is there any specific technique to parse the link tags in rss feed.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
```

where website is the link tag from the rss feed **http://www.mobileapp.pcmac.org/mobile/xml/sisapp.asp?sid=353&pn=news2**

When I hard-coded the link tag value in place of website it is working fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: i am getting the following Error:Http error fetching url

Comment: this is the websiteurl-http://www.mcpss.com/?PN='News2'&SubP='DNewsStory'&gn=&NewsID=47560&ShowNav=&StoryGroup=Current when i hardcode the value it is working